# Marklogic Data hub: Triples are not generated in the Mapping output file

Tags: marklogic

I am using the latest versions of Marklogic datahub and MarkLogic Server.

- Data Hub 5.4.1 QuickStart
- MarkLogic Server Version 10.0-6.2

In MarkLogic Datahub, I have created a flow for a data source.

Here the data source is reading data from csv files.

I have created an entity and I am able to do the Ingestion and Mapping.

After executing the Ingestion and Mapping steps, I have observed that the triples do not get generated in the mapping output file.

Am I missing some steps here which is required for the data hub to generate the triples in the Mapping output file?

I kindly request you to help me in this regard.

Thank You.

[image: Data Hub Flows]
[image: Entity]
[image: Mapping_Flow]
[image: Ingestion_Output_File]
[image: Mapping_Output_File]

Comment: QuickStart is not officially supported for DHF 5.4 and up. You should switch to Data Hub Central Community Edition: https://github.com/marklogic-community/data-hub-central-community

Comment: Don't bother about embedded triples. See also my comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard data hub mapping flow never fills in the triples section of the envelope.

By default, neither does a custom mapping step, unless you explicitly put some triples in there.

However, if you have defined an entity and mapped to it, then the data hub will insert triples into the triple index under the covers.

You can verify this on your database by going into query console, selecting the Final database, and running the following SparQL query:

```
select ?s ?p ?o
where
{
  ?s ?p ?o.
}
```

You should see a whole bunch of triples in there where the subject starts with "http://marklogic.com/row/" and the predicate will start with "http://marklogic.com/column/..."

If you want to fill in the triples section of the envelope with your own triples, then you've got three choices:

1. Add a custom hook to your mapping step that adds the triples into the envelope's triple section;
2. Add a custom step after your mapping step that works from Final to Final that fills in the triples section; or
3. Convert your mapping step to a custom mapping step, and write JavaScript code to do your property mapping, and add the triples as part of the same flow.

Comment: I would typically not bother about that triples section. Use a TDE if you need SQL of SPARQL access to your data. It makes sure your envelope remains clean; no unnecessary duplication of data inside the envelope.

Comment: Also note that row triples aren't really meant as true triples, and only show up if you deployed a TDE that defines an SQL view on entity. The subject values might look like IRIs, but are in fact RowIDs..